# "MySql server has gone away" when I increase the size of data to be added to the table

Tags: php, mysql, database

There are 2 pages in my application. index.html and submit.php. Index page has 8 text editors and 4 upload buttons for images. With POST request the form is being submitted to submit.php. I am able to get every bit of data via POST request but when I add that data in MySql server it displays error "MySql server has gone away". When I decrease the data that is present in rich text editors the querying is successful. Is there a way something can be done about this? Should I change my Database.
I am using WAMP currently. Size of images are in KB's and i am storing images as BLOB.
I have already added statements

```
ini_set('short_open_tag', 'on');
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

EDIT: mysql_error() is displaying that row size is too large > 8126. But when I save say 6 of text editor's info. then it gets saved but if I try to save them all I get the error. Is there anyway I can prevent that?

Comment: Have you checked the mysql / php error log? This will give you a better understand as to what is happening.

Comment: I have edited it, please check through. All my logs are clear. Please let me know if you require any other info.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to configure the MySQL server (my.ini on Windows) make sure there is:

```
[mysqld]
    max_allowed_packet=16M
```

in there - or any sufficiently high number
**((** in some cases you wont see any `max_allowed_packet` under `[mysqld]` in you my.ini...that means its using there default value 1mb.in such cases you will need to add that line under `[mysqld]`**))**

and also edit php.ini with following changes

```
post_max_size=128M
upload_max_filesize=128M
```

**EDIT 1:**

your problem is the row size limit for InnoDB tables, in this links you can find some approaches to solve this:..this is very complex concept honestly..try to go through following links

[innodb row size](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/04/07/innodb-row-size-limitation/)
and [Limits on Table Column Count and Row Size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html)

Comment: did that. Still no luck. Getting:::::ERROR::"Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline."

Comment: See my latest post on that error message : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45862/877

Answer (score 0):

MySQL-s default connection length is somewhere around 8 hours. If your connection is longer than that, you may have to build in reconnection logic. After a long period of idle time I recommend doing a MySQL ping before issuing any queries.